# How to add 'style' in dynamically created table?

Tags: javascript

I have created table through DOM, now want to add style to that table but its not working.
**code :**

```
<script>
    var nrCols=4;
    var maxRows=10;
    var nrRows=maxRows+1;
    while(nrRows>maxRows)
    {
        nrRows=Number(prompt('How many rows? Maximum '+maxRows+' allowed.',''));
    }
    var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var tab=document.createElement('table');
    var style=document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('background-color','red');
    tab.appendChild(style);

    tab.setAttribute('Border','1');

    tab.className="mytable";
    var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');

    var tr1= document.createElement('tr');
    var th1= document.createElement('th');
    th1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('No.'));

    var th2= document.createElement('th');
    th2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Surah.'));

    tr1.appendChild(th1);
    tr1.appendChild(th2);
    tbo.appendChild(tr1);

    var row, cell;
    for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
        row=document.createElement('tr');
        for(var j=0;j<nrCols;j++){
            cell=document.createElement('td');
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Allah'+' '+j))
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tbo.appendChild(row);
    }
    tab.appendChild(tbo);
    root.appendChild(tab);
</script>
```

i have used `style.setAttribute('background-color','red');` but no difference. how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you used a debugger (built into any modern browser) to inspect the DOM and see if the attribute is actually set?

Comment: CSS properties aren't attributes. Try `style.style.backgroundColor = 'red'` or `style.setAttribute('style','background-color:red')`

Comment: Why are you creating a `createElement('style')` element? Just apply individual style properties to the tags you want to target. `tab.style.backgroundColor = 'red'` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var style=document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('background-color','red');
    tab.appendChild(style);
```

with :

```
tab.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

All elements have a style attribute to which you can add the appropriate style values.

Comment: if i want to increase width of that table forcefully , then ?

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi tab.style.width

Answer (score 0):

try to change the name of var style it might be causing the css style confusion, try this way

```
var menu = document.createElement("menu");
menu.style.backgroundColor = "#555";
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, `style` is a HTML tag, when you create a element with that name it expects CSS info inside it. You maybe want this:

If you want to target the `<th>` element you should use this instead:

```
var th1 = document.createElement('th');
th1.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fdug4/2/)

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi, which ones do you want to target?

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi, updated the answer with new demo. Why did you accept the other answer? Does it work for you?

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi, but then you get the whole table red, you said you wanted just `<th>`...

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi, sure, just checking you are aware that his answer makes this: http://jsfiddle.net/Fdug4/3/

Answer (score -2):

it should be something like this

```
 document.body.style.backgroundColor="#333333";
```

in your case

```
 tab.style.backgroundColor="#333333"
```

Below code will create style tag

```
 var css = 'table { background: red; }'
 var style = document.createElement('style');
 style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
```